# Read variables from file into Fabric's env dictionary

Tags: environment-variables, fabric

I know you can set Fabric's [env](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/env.html) items using [--set](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/fab.html#cmdoption--set) flag:

```
fab --set A=1,B=2 my_task
```

And those variables will be available into *fabfile.py*:

```
print(env.A) # will print 1
```

The question is, **is it possible to get those variables straight from a *.env* file**? Eg:

```
A=1
B=2
...
```

Executing something like `fab --env-file .env my_task` (much alike [docker run's env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) flag)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `--config` [option](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-c). It allows you to:

> Sets env.rcfile to the given file path, which Fabric will try to load on startup and use to update environment variables.

The command:

```
fab --config .env my_task
```